# How to use javascript code inside Razor

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller

i am trying to use javascript variable inside razor. how can i do it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = @(Model.questions == null ? 0 : Model.questions.Count);
$("#Add").on('click', function (e) {
        $("#sorular").append(`<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-1">Question</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.questions[${ counter + 1}].Soru)
              </div>
              </div>`);
        counter += 1;
    });
</script>
```

in the 6th line "counter" variable is a javascript and i need to use it inside this line. i tried to use $ but its returning an error.

Comment: Have you also included the `jQuery` library since you are using `jQuery` in the source code above? A syntax error of **$  is not defined** normally indicates no `jQuery` library has been loaded.

Comment: yes i did . the error is counter doesnot exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JS variables on Razor code, but you cant use your own `ViewBag` to do it:

```
@{
     var counter = (Model.questions == null ? 0 : Model.questions.Count);
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.questions[counter + 1].Soru)
```

Comment: i tried : 
@{
     var counter = (Model.questions == null ? 0 : Model.questions.Count);
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.questions[counter + 1].Soru) @{counter += 1; } but the result of counter is always 1

Comment: Then is a problem with your model, **not** with the JavaScript of your question